# How can I extract, label and data.frame values from Console in a loop?

Tags: r, loops, extract, summary, nls

I made a nls loop and get values calculated in console. Now I want to extract those values, specify which values are from which group and put everything in a dataframe to continue working.

**my loop so far:**

```
for (i in seq_along(trtlist2)) { loopmm.nls <- 
  nls(rate ~ (Vmax * conc /(Km + conc)), 
      data=subset(M3, M3$trtlist==trtlist2[i]),
      start=list(Km=200, Vmax=2),  trace=TRUE )

summary(loopmm.nls)
print(summary(loopmm.nls))
}
```

**the output in console:** (this is what I want to extract and put in a dataframe, I have this same "parameters" thing like 20 times)

```
Parameters:
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
Km   23.29820    9.72304   2.396   0.0228 *  
Vmax  0.10785    0.01165   9.258 1.95e-10 ***
---
```

different ways of extracting data from the console that work but not in the loop (so far!)

```
#####extract data in diff ways from nls##### 

## extract coefficients as matrix  

Kinall <- summary(mm.nls)$parameters 

  
## extract coefficients save as dataframe 

Kin <- as.data.frame(Kinall) 

colnames(Kin)  <- c("values", "SE", "T", "P") 

  
###create Km Vmax df 

Kms <- Kin[1, ] 

Vmaxs <- Kin[2, ] 
 

#####extract coefficients each manually 

Km <- unname(coef(summary(mm.nls))["Km", "Estimate"]) 

Vmax <- unname(coef(summary(mm.nls))["Vmax", "Estimate"]) 
 

KmSE <- unname(coef(summary(mm.nls))["Km", "Std. Error"]) 

VmaxSE <- unname(coef(summary(mm.nls))["Vmax", "Std. Error"]) 

  
KmP <- unname(coef(summary(mm.nls))["Km", "Pr(>|t|)"]) 

VmaxP <- unname(coef(summary(mm.nls))["Vmax", "Pr(>|t|)"]) 

  

KmT <- unname(coef(summary(mm.nls))["Km", "t value"]) 

VmaxT <- unname(coef(summary(mm.nls))["Vmax", "t value"])
```

one thing that works if you extract data through append, but somehow that only works for "estimates" not the rest

```
Kms <- append(Kms, unname(coef(loopmm.nls)["Km"] ))
Vmaxs <- append(Vmaxs, unname(coef(loopmm.nls)["Vmax"] )) 
}
Kindf <- data.frame(trt = trtlist2, Vmax = Vmaxs, Km = Kms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just keep everything in the dataframe for ease. You can nest by the group and then run the regression then pull the coefficients out. Just make sure you have `tidyverse` and `broom` installed on your computer.

```r
library(tidyverse)


#example
mtcars |>
  nest(data = -cyl) |>
  mutate(model = map(data, ~nls(mpg~hp^b, 
                                data = .x, 
                                start = list(b = 1))),
         clean_mod = map(model, broom::tidy))  |>
  unnest(clean_mod) |>
  select(-c(data, model))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>     cyl term  estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     6 b        0.618    0.0115      53.6 2.83e- 9
#> 2     4 b        0.731    0.0217      33.7 1.27e-11
#> 3     8 b        0.504    0.0119      42.5 2.46e-15


#what I expect will work for your data
All_M3_models <- M3 |>
  nest(data = -trtlist) |>
  mutate(model = map(data, ~nls(rate ~ (Vmax * conc /(Km + conc)), 
                                data=.x,
                                start=list(Km=200, Vmax=2))),
         clean_mod = map(model, broom::tidy))|>
  unnest(clean_mod) |>
  select(-c(data, model))
```